# I need help translating this to a array based input rather than using a file based input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have this code here but I was wondering instead of using a TextFile for input, how can I achieve this using an array based input using the same numbers

```
Dim numbers(5), x As Integer
Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("DATA.TXT")
Do While sr.Peek <> -1
x = CInt(sr.ReadLine)
numbers(x) += 2
Loop
sr.Close()
txtBox.Text = CStr(numbers(3))
```

Assume the six rows of the file DATA.TXT contain the following entries: 5, 3, 1, 3,1, 3, 1

The CStr(numbers(3)) should result in a 6.

Comment: Don’t declare variables before using them. In particular, declare `x` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the numbers from the file into an array, you can use a For loop to iterate over all the values:

```
Dim numbers(5) As Integer
Dim followingEntries = {5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1}

For i = 0 To followingEntries.Length - 1
    Dim x = followingEntries(i)
    numbers(x) += 2
Next

txtBox.Text = CStr(numbers(3))
```

Note that array indexes start at 0 for the first item.

Answer (score 0):

My vb.net is little old but this should be near what you are searching for.

```
dim source as string = "5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1"
dim x as integer
Dim numbers(5)

for each val in source.Split(",")
    x = CInt(val.Trim())
    numbers(x) += 2
next
```

Comment: Do u have something that is VB.net 2017

Comment: @xGamer11221Productions What makes you think this won’t work with VB 2017?